# What is the pin diameter for this part?

Tags: pcb, drawing, dimensions

What is the required pad diameter for the following part ?

[HM2J07PE5118N9LF](http://portal.fciconnect.com/Comergent//fci/drawing/bsc202767006.pdf)

Maybe its late and I'm just not seeing ? The recommended PCB hole layout usually contains this information but I just don't see it.

Comment: Not sure if the document in note 8 covers it, I had a really quick look and couldn't find it but might be worth a further look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @PeterJ comment, see http://portal.fciconnect.com/Comergent//fci/drawing/bsa201572001.pdf for the through hole pad dimensions. 0.7mm to 0.65mm after through hole plating.

Comment: And damn was that non-obvious as hell to find.

Comment: Ya it wasnt easy. I thought maybe I just wasnt seeing it. Good to know that i wasn't the only one. Thanks again!